# Logic Gates: Realize OR gate using ONLY XOR gates

Tags: computer-science, logic

I am doing some revision for my exams and one of the questions that frequently asked in last year question paper is how to realize a OR gate using only XOR gates. I am trying to do from last 1 hour and also searched on Internet. But failed. Hope to get some help here.

Answer (score 19):

You can't derive an OR (or AND, NOR, NAND) gate from only XOR (or XNOR) gates, because they are not universal gates.

> Here is an argument against XOR and
> XNOR as universal gates.
>
> An XOR gate
> is a parity generator. Cascading
> parity generators always produce
> parity generators. AND and OR are not
> parity functions.
>
> An XOR gate can be
> used as an inverter. An XNOR gate is
> an XOR followed by an inverter, so it
> is also a parity generator.

To be an universal gate, a gate needs to satisfy both the following conditions:

1. You should be able to create an inverter using the gate.
2. You should be able to block the input (i.e. setting N - 1 inputs to 0 or 1, the remaining input is ignored)

Comment: I noticed you indented the middle part of your answer. Is this a quote from something, and if so, where?

Answer (score -1):

Tie both input lines to only one input pin of the XOR gate, leaving the other input pin as always being false, thus producing an OR gate.

Comment: "Tying both input lines" is called wired-or in electronics design - and a) is usually not permissible (can actually damage hardware) and b) would be an OR gate :)